# Is it possible to pin an application to the taskbar on a secondary display?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have "Show taskbar on all displays" set to enabled and taskbar buttons are set to show where the window is open. Under these settings, there are no pinned shortcuts on the secondary display; only currently open applications are shown.

I would like to be able to pin a separate set of applications to the secondary taskbar. I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have tried dragging a desktop shortcut to the taskbar, but the icon gets a red cross over it. I have also tried right-click for a "Pin this application" option, but none appear.

It looks to me like the only way to get *any* pinned programs on the secondary taskbar is to set "Show taskbar buttons on" to "All taskbars".

Is there any configuration option available or method to get pinned applications on the secondary taskbar?

Comment: Sadly the same problem still seems to exist in Windows 10. :-(

Comment: Any updates on this in 2016?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature is not included in Windows 8. This is widely acknowledged in various articles:

- > In case you would like to pin a shortcut to main taskbar, yes this will work as it used to work on Windows 7, however you will not be able to pin a shortcut specifically to any non primary taskbar.

  [Windows 8 Multi Monitor](http://www.dual-monitor.biz/2011/09/14/windows-8-multi-monitor/)
- > Pinning apps on the Taskbar only goes so far before it’s full… although it would be great if i could pin apps to the taskbar on my second monitor

  [How to live without the Windows 8 Start menu](http://www.poremsky.com/windows/how-to-live-without-the-windows-8-start-menu/)
- > However, choosing this option doesn't offer you the ability to pin the program to secondary taskbars.

  [Enable pinning in secondary Taskbars in windows 8](http://tweaker.uservoice.com/forums/73857-general/suggestions/3086447-enable-pinning-in-secondary-taskbars-in-windows-8)

Free alternatives to include more shortcuts on the limited space of the primary taskbar includes using a **Taskbar Toolbar**, as discussed in [How to live without the Windows 8 Start menu](http://www.poremsky.com/windows/how-to-live-without-the-windows-8-start-menu/). You can also bring the start menu back, using a 3rd party application:

- [ViStart](http://lee-soft.com/vistart/) (free!)
- [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/) (free!)
- [Pokki](https://www.pokki.com/) (free!)
- [StartMenu7](http://www.startmenu7.com/index.html) (free with pro version for sale)

---

A non-free way is using *Actual Multiple Monitors*, who say (quoted):

> In Actual Multiple Monitors, you can have different sets of pinned applications on different monitors. You can pin an icon in any of the following ways:
>
> - via context menu command
> - via drag-n-drop of the application's shortcut

Unfortunately it costs $29.95, with a 30-day trial period. I could not find a free alternative, but hopefully there will be one soon.

*Use at your own risk: It appears a link to the relevant site is not allowed (filtered) on Super User, and after investigating, [Antivir found a possible trojan](http://tinyurl.com/9tfhsud)*

Comment: AMM is blacklisted for spamming in the past I believe - there's a reference to this in the [Ask a SU Mod Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6628524#6628524)

Comment: Ok, I intend to replace it with a free alternative, when available, anyways.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. Could you perhaps cite the "various articles" that reference this issue? I tried Google before I asked this question, and I tried again after reading your answer. Still haven't found anything specifically regarding this.

Comment: not sure why it is important, since they only reference the problem, not the issue, but I added them

Answer (score 3):

[Dual Monitor Taskbar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmonitortb) helped me with the same problem. Just turn off your second monitor's taskbar in Windows and let this be there. You can configure it to have a clock or not, show the notification area or not and - what we've been looking for - a way to pin programs to the second monitor's taskbar.

There are configurations to allow it to run when Windows starts and it works well in Windows 8 64-bit.