# Enable task bar auto-hide only for the second screen in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-preview

While I like having the task bar on my second screen in Windows 8 (And 8.1), I would prefer that is was in auto-hide mode so that windows can fill the entire screen. However the auto-hide option in the task bar properties effects the primary screen as well. This means I must choose to have no task bar on the second screen, have an always visible task bar on the second screen, or have the task bar on my primary screen in auto-hide mode. I don't like any of those options.

Dose anyone know of a way to enable auto-hide for only the second screen? Display Fusion has the feature, but that only applies to its replacement task bars. And you have to pay for it.

Comment: You may want to check out this question: http://superuser.com/questions/495874/can-i-extend-my-taskbar-across-multiple-monitors It seems to be a feature you can turn on or off by going to Multiple Displays under Taskbar Properties

Comment: @CLockeWork That is the task bar properties menu, which lacks any way to enable this feature on a screen-to-screen basis. Hence my question.

Comment: My appologies, i've only got Win 7 here, which doesn't extend the task bar across multiple screens anyway. The answer provided does seem to allude to being able to turn off the task bar on secondary screens, but then again, if you're specificly after auto-hide then I guess it won't help. Hence why this was a comment not an answer :)